# How to automatically update ontology properties by accessing information from web?

Tags: rdf, owl, ontology, protege

I have made a local ontology and provided some properties to its individuals.
I have published it on LoD cloud, now I wish that the ontology gets updated automatically with current information from WHO website.
Can you suggest a way for it?
How do i connect the ontology from the website?

Comment: what means "published on LoD cloud"?

Comment: and what is the question now? I mean, you created an ontology with Protege and now? How did you add which data from WHO to your ontology? And updating means you have to write code, either Java, Python or whatever and use one the existing APIs - then you also have to somehow "connect" your application to the WHO page - either there is some web service or you have to write your own scraping code. Then extract whatever data and add/replace your existing data. that's it. So, do you think this question is appropriate for StackOverflow?

Comment: Also, if you're working on COVID-19 challenge, check the existing projects first. Most if not all things and apps have already been created on the COVID-19 data from plenty of sources. Nothing will be new when you're doing basically the same. Anyways, good luck, sound like a long way if you don't know how to use ontologies at all. So you should start here and understand their purpose.

Answer (score 1):

"Connecting an ontology to a web site" is a common question but there is no good general answer because the question is too general. There are many possible approaches depending on the specific ontology, the specific web site, the data formats for the information of interest and the use that will be made of the information.

You have to identify what information you wish to extract from the web site, which format will it be available in, and when/how often to retrieve that information. For example, do you need the items the web site exposes through its RSS feed, or do you need the text content on the main page? There might be tools to access one or the other, but there is no single tool to do both.

After you've extracted the data, updating your ontology is comparatively simple, but the only tool you mention is Protege. Do you plan to do the updates by hand? If not, you should mention which library you plan to use. They all have documentation for basic tasks like loading, modifying and saving an ontology. If you meet with troubles implementing those operations, add the relevant information to your question.